# Rails/Puma with Apache HTTPD proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, puma

I want to use Puma with HTTPD to serve my Rails application. As far as I can tell there aren't very many examples of people doing such a thing. I know nginx has some benefits over HTTPD, and that Passenger makes a lot of things easy, but is there a reason to **not** use Puma/HTTPD?

I've skimmed through a few examples online and put together an HTTPD config block that I like and that seems to be working fine (though I haven't done any performance testing). Am I missing anything? This seems easier/more simple than most Puma/nginx or Passenger/HTTPD setups, which makes me a little worried.

```
<VirtualHost *:3008>
  DocumentRoot MY_RAILS_ROOT/public
  ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
  ProxyPass /robots.txt !
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(404|422|500).html$ !
  ProxyPass /assets/ !

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9292/ # Puma bind address
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9292/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In our project we have varnish->nginx->puma stack and it works very well. Nginx is more robust, fast and powerfull in general, and it's memory consumption is less than httpd.
Anyway, did you really need HTTPD?:) Read about architecture of httpd (modular) and nginx (modules compiled in). But if performance it's not a problem, and you know well httpd, use it :)

EDIT:
Think about start puma in unix sock mode, it gain some performance improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common usage of Apache HTTPD as a reverse proxy, so there are no particular issues. Are you running both the web server and puma on the same machine? It might be a good idea to split them to prevent issues with memory consumption, the TCP stack and any other contention that may occur under high load.

If you have multiple puma nodes then you can use HTTPD to perform load balancing across all nodes like this:

```
<VirtualHost example.org:80>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org

    ErrorLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log 
    CustomLog /srv/www/example.org/logs/access.log combined

    DocumentRoot MY_RAILS_ROOT/public

    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
        BalancerMember http://app1.example.org
        BalancerMember http://app2.example.org
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
    ProxyPass /robots.txt !
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(404|422|500).html$ !
    ProxyPass /assets/ !

    ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/
    # enumerate all nodes for proxypassreverse since it adds a trailing slash :( bugid 51982
    ProxyPassReverse / http://app1.example.org
    ProxyPassReverse / http://app2.example.org


    # ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/ lbmethod=byrequests
    # ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/ lbmethod=bytraffic
    # ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/ lbmethod=bybusyness
</VirtualHost>
```

Although if you have a better HA option (ie AWS ELBs, HAProxy, Varnish or anything )  then I would prefer that as you get Layer 7 availability checks for free